# Is it possible to run an Android JUnit test with errors in the project?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, junit

Is there a way to run an Android JUnit test when there's an error in another file in the project (a different test that's still under development)? Specifically, I'm trying to run test A by right clicking it in Eclipse and selecting Run As -> Android JUnit Test. There's an error in test B, so when I try to run A, I get the following message:

> Android Launch
>
> Your project contains error(s), please fix them before running your application.

B is still under development and isn't being tested at the moment, so I want to ignore the errors in it if possible. The only way I could come up with was commenting out the body of test B, but this is a pain.

Sorry if this has been answered before. I searched for it, but the only answers I could find were for questions in which the person didn't know where the errors were.

I'm using Eclipse Juno Service Release 2, Android API 19 (4.4.2), and JUnit 3.

Comment: i think, your question is legitimate. but de facto it's not a question how to run a JUnit test. the answer is, you must be able to compile the complete project. otherwise you don't have something you can upload to the device. more i would say, this is part of a good project coordination, which modules are available at which time and what are the interfaces to test.

Answer (score 0):

No it isn't. The problem is with the compiler, which can't compile that code.
The only way for the code to compile, is for you to comment it out, otherwise the compiler will keep complaining about it.
You can just add // to the beginning of each line of the testing code, and it should compile just fine.
I'm afraid this is the only way.

Comment: I stumbled across a way to do what I wanted completely by accident:
If I right-click the file with errors and select Build Path -> Exclude, I'm able to compile and run the rest of the code without problems.

Comment: You should consider adding that as a question and accepting it, for others to know that you've found a way to solve your problem and to help others with a similar problem.